# Pause Node csv-parser when uploading data

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I am working with Node [csv-parser](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) and my read stream is from std in. I am piping that to the parser. Inside the parser readable function, I am making an async HTTP call to upload this data. During this time, I want the parser to pause reading. Until the async call has finished excecuting.

```js
var parse = require('csv-parse');
  var output = [];
// Create the parser
  var parser = parse({delimiter: ',', columns: true, trim: true});
  
  parser.on('readable', function () {
    while (record = parser.read()) {
      console.log('Still reading');
      var jsonRec = convertIpToInt(record);
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonRec);
      output.push(new Buffer(jsonData + "\n"));
      //parser.pause();
      var assertPromise = uploadBatches1(indexName, function() {
          //parser.resume();
          console.log('Returned');
      });
     }
  });

  function uploadBatches1(indexToAssert, cb) {
    //uploads data got form parser
  }
```

Comment: did you have a chance to see if my answer below helped you?  Do you need more information or assistance?

Answer (score 3):

Since csv-parse exposes a readable stream, you can pause the stream with   `parser.pause()`

Likewise, when your update is complete, you can call `parser.resume()`.  You can also check if you need to resume beforehand using `parser.isPaused()`.

You can read more about readable streams and what the pause method does here:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pause

Based on the above, you should be implementing the `parser.on('data')` readable stream event, instead of the `while (record = parser.read())` loop.  Pausing the stream does nothing if you are actively calling the read method yourself.

Consider restructuring your code like so, and then use parser.pipe from a filesystem read:

```js
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var output = [];
// Create the parser
var parser = parse({delimiter: ',', columns: true, trim: true});

parser.on('data', function () {
  console.log('Still reading');
  var jsonRec = convertIpToInt(record);
  var jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonRec);
  output.push(new Buffer(jsonData + "\n"));
  parser.pause();
  var assertPromise = uploadBatches1(indexName, function() {
      parser.resume();
      console.log('Returned');
  });
});

function uploadBatches1(indexToAssert, cb) {
  //uploads data got form parser
}
```